# SQLAlchemy equivalent of Django ORM's relationship-spanning filter

Tags: python, django-models, sqlalchemy

This example is from the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/).

Given the (Django) database model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
```

In Django I can use:

```
Entry.objects.filter(blog__name__exact='Beatles Blog')
```

to get all `Entry` objects for blogs with the specified name.

**Question**: What is the equivalent SQLAlchemy statement, given the model definition below?

```
class Blog(Base):
    __tablename__ = "blog"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(100))

class Entry(Base):
    __tablename__ = "entry"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    blogid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Blog.id))
    headline = Column(Unicode(255))
    body_text = Column(UnicodeText)

    blog = relationship(Blog, backref="entries")
```

**EDIT**

I believe there are two ways to accomplish this:

```
>>> q = session.query
>>> print q(Entry).join(Blog).filter(Blog.name == u"One blog")
SELECT entry.id AS entry_id, entry.blogid AS entry_blogid, entry.headline AS entry_headline, entry.body_text AS entry_body_text 
FROM entry JOIN blog ON blog.id = entry.blogid 
WHERE blog.name = ?

>>> print q(Entry).filter(Entry.blog.has(Blog.name == u"One blog"))
SELECT entry.id AS entry_id, entry.blogid AS entry_blogid, entry.headline AS entry_headline, entry.body_text AS entry_body_text 
FROM entry 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM blog 
WHERE blog.id = entry.blogid AND blog.name = ?)

# ... and of course
>>> blog = q(Blog).filter(Blog.name == u"One blog")
>>> q(Entry).filter(Entry.blog == blog)
```

A few more questions:

1. Are there other ways to accomplish this using SQLAlchemy than the ones above?
2. Would it not make sense if you could do `session.query(Entry).filter(Entry.blog.name == u"One blog")` in many-to-one relationships?
3. What SQL does Django's ORM produce in this case?

Comment: I think `session.query(Entry).filter(Entry.blog.name == u"One blog")` makes sense.... I tried to use it first time I use SQLAlchemy.. I think SQLAlchemy sucks at this point.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53062870/sqlachemy-filter-by-relationship-like-django-orm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
session.query(model.Entry).join((model.Blog, model.Entry.blogid==model.Blog.id)).filter(model.Blog.name=='Beatles Blog').all()
```

Comment: No need to specify the join condition, SA works that out based on the foreign keys. ``session.query(Entry).join(Blog).filter(Blog.name == ...)`` does the trick.

Comment: True, but it won't hurt and in more complex queries you're safer like this and i personally think it improves readability a little.

Comment: @Bogdan: eh, not when it makes you have to scroll to read it =p

Answer (score 2):

I also always dreamed of having Django-like "magic joins". I'm familiar with 
`sqlalchemy-django-query` it, I found that it's not powerful enough for my tasks.

That's why I created
**https://github.com/absent1706/sqlalchemy-mixins#django-like-queries**.

It works similar to `sqlalchemy-django-query` but has more additional features ([here's a comparison](https://github.com/absent1706/sqlalchemy-mixins#django-like-queries-1)). Also it's well tested and documented.

Answer (score 1):

Already late to the party, but i stumbled across this:
https://github.com/mitsuhiko/sqlalchemy-django-query/blob/master/sqlalchemy_django_query.py

This tries to build queries using the django notation.

From the docs: `Post.query.filter_by(pub_date__year=2008)`