# sqlachemy: filter by relationship (like django orm)?

Tags: python, django-models, sqlalchemy

In django ORM you can directly filter by relationship attributes. Eg, given the tables

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    color = models.TextField()

class Sale(models.Model):
    sale_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can do

```
Sale.objects.filter(product__color__in=['red', 'blue'])
```

Or even the other way around

```
Product.objects.filter(sale__timestamp__gt=datetime.now())
```

What is the proper way of doing this in sqlalchemy, *without explicit JOIN*s??

Comment: Related, though you don't seem to like the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113029/sqlalchemy-equivalent-of-django-orms-relationship-spanning-filter. I think these 2 questions should be merged, but it is hard to say which way. Yours is clearer.

Comment: @IljaEverilä: yep, I don't like the answer :). using explicit joins feels to defeat the purpose of having relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`any()` and `has()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-exists) to filter based on non-scalar and scalar relationships. They produce EXISTS subquery expressions:

```
session.query(Product).filter(Product.sales.any(Sale.timestamp > datetime.now()))
```

and

```
session.query(Sale).filter(Sale.product.has(Product.color.in_(['red', 'blue'])))
```

Unfortunately on some DBMS the EXISTS subquery expressions may perform poorly, compared to using explicit joins.

Comment: regarding performance effect, do you know about postgres in particular?

Comment: Postgresql should be fine as far as I know. It uses for example semijoins in the actual query plan to perform the EXISTS.